# Android AsyncTask, handle unavailable server

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am using this tutorial:
http://hmkcode.com/android-parsing-json-data/ to get JSON data from server on virtual machine. It works fine, when server is turned on, but my app crashes when server is unavailable.
How should I handle this situation?

After pressing button I execute:

```
httpAsyncTask.execute("http://localhost:3000"); //changed on purpose, it works with given IP
```

httpAsyncTask class:

```
private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            return GET(urls[0]);
    }

    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Worked fine", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        goToMyActivity();
    }
}
```

In debug my app stops at:

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
```

int GET method:

```
public static String GET(String url){
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = "";

        try {
            // create HttpClient
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            // make GET request to the given URL
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
            // receive response as inputStream
            inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
            // convert inputstream to string
            if (inputStream != null)
                result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
            else
                result = "Did not work!";
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("Http:",e.toString());
        }
    return result;
}
```

Caught exception was null.

Comment: Please include the relevant code and stack trace of the crash in your question.

Comment: use `HttpURLConnection` to make sure the connection is established.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `getResponseCode();` of `HttpURLConnection` class to make sure that the connection is established successfully.

`getResponseCode();` would return `200` if the connection is successful.

```
                int responseCode = -1;
                feedURL = "your URL"
                HttpURLConnection connection;
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) feedURL.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
```

then use `if` block to check if `200` is returned by `connection.getResponseCode()`.
the constant `HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK` can be used instead of hard coding `200`.

```
                if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                      // do your stuff here
                }
                else { 
                     // Show some error dialog or Toast message
                }
```

Comment: I got: "failed to connect to /localhost (port 3000): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)" error. repornseCode was still -1

Comment: try increasing the time, `connection.setConnectTimeout(time in milliseconds)` and  
`connection.setReadTimeout(time in milliseconds)`

Comment: Now it crashes on:    connection.connect();
And goes to catch clasue:
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

Comment: please show your `logcat` output and your complete code after adding my code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the catch block to catch the timeout exception (and others):

```
String message = "";
try {
    //HTTP stuff here
    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        // do your stuff here
    } else { 
        // Show some error dialog or Toast message
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    message  = e.getLocalizedMessage();
    e.printStackTrace();
}
// Toast message
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will return null if it gets timeout otherwise will send the response

> public static String Get(String url) {
>
> ```
>   // Create a new HttpClient
>   HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
>   // set your timeouts here
>   HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 5000);
>   HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 10000);
>   HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);      
>
>   try {
>       // Execute HTTP GET Request
>       HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));           
>       return EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
>
>   } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
>       e.printStackTrace();
>   } catch (IOException e) {
>       e.printStackTrace();
>   }
>   return null;
> ```
>
> }